# Work flow triggers for files and folders only

Tags: github-actions

I'm using this on: syntax to trigger a workflow when a file in a folder changes or a specific file changes. But for some reason, this is triggering also on any tag even though I tell it to a normal tags.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '.cicd/**'
      - '.github/workflows/cicd-sync.yaml'
      - 'cicd.yaml'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "**on send text to trigger a workflow**" and "**even though I tell it to a normal tags**"?

Comment: You can exclude a path by negating it with `!` e.g. `paths: ['!refs/tags**']`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore for more examples and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet.

Comment: @azeem typo on syntax to trigger*

Comment: Didn't realize refs were a path. I'll test it out. I did try this to ignore tags. 
```on:
  push:
    paths-include:
      - '.cicd/**'
      - './.github/workflows/cicd-sync.yaml'
      - './cicd.yaml'
    tags-ignore: '*'
 ```

Comment: Tried this and it still triggers on a tag. it also didn't want to fire on the cicd.yaml file change until I tagged, and future tags on the same commit. I wonder if I found some edge case bug? I've tried this 3 different ways now. I must be missing something. I've also tried variations with `path-exclude:`.

Comment: Please update your question with an **UPDATE** heading and include what you tried in there. Some combinations of configurations are mutually exclusive e.g. if one is mentioned, the other one is skipped. You might want to check those from the docs and handle those accordingly.

Comment: Regarding tags, you might want to observe the difference between pushing a tag from the command line and adding a tag directly from the GitHub UI. Those might be different events altogether and need to be handled as required.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts at this, I have found the solution to my issue.
Here is how we got it to work

```
  push:
    paths:
      - '.cicd/**'
      - '.github/workflows/cicd-sync.yaml'
      - 'cicd.yaml'
    branches:
      - "**"
    ignore-tags:
      - '**'
```